# PDO <-> SQL Server exec (in Laravel) returns empty array

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, ssms

PHP, Laravel, calling

```
$db->select("EXEC [dbo].[sp_StoredProc1] 1, 3, 1, '2016-06-12 00:00:00', '2016-09-12 00:00:00'");
```

**RESULT** - EMPTY ARRAY!!!

Calling the same function via SQL Server Management Studio:

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_StoredProc1] 1, 3, 1, '2016-06-12 00:00:00', '2016-09-12 00:00:00'
```

**RESULT** - VALID TABLE.

Any idea, why this might happen is warmly appreciated

Comment: Do you got `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your SP?

Answer (score 3):

The cause for this - is an ERROR in PHP PDO for MS SQL Server.
Exception is not thrown despite happens.
The very alike case is depicted here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1754869-392-1.aspx

So it is sort of 2 step problems:

1. When stored procedure parameters are not EXPLICITLY set to NULL/NOT NULL they are inherited, what causes exception...
2. which is NOT Shown by PDO (the bug is in Laravel PDO).

Also, you might see this thread
[PHP - PDOException is not thrown on error, an empty array returned (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467221/php-pdoexception-is-not-thrown-on-error-an-empty-array-returned-sql-server)
My colleague did better investigation than me for this issue :)))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("EXEC [dbo].[sp_StoredProc1] 1, 3, 1, '2016-06-12 00:00:00', '2016-09-12 00:00:00'");
```

You can also try to see what you get when you but both the `DB::select(...)` part and just the `DB::raw("...")` part in a `dd()` die and dump function;