# PHP - PDOException is not thrown on error, an empty array returned (SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

If I understand right I'm using following stack: PHP <-> PDO <-> MS SQL DBLIB <-> freetds <-> MS SQL Server.

```
$pdo = new \PDO('dblib:host=192.168.0.10:1433;dbname=MyDb;charset=UTF-8', 'mydb', 'secret', [
    \PDO::ATTR_CASE => \PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => \PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
    \PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
]);
$statement = $pdo->prepare("EXEC [dbo].[sp_MyStoredProcedure] 1, 2, 3");
if ( ! $statement->execute()) {
    throw new \ErrorException('Error executing sp_MyStoredProcedure');
}
$data = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I'm setting `ERRMODE` to `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, and there is an error *515* happens in stored procedure, but no exception is thrown, why? `$data` is storing empty array and I was considering this as proper result of executing stored procedure. To overcome this issue I've added check `$statement->errorInfo()[1]`, through I'm not sure if it proper to check error in this way:

```
if ( ! $statement->execute() || $statement->errorInfo()[1]) {
    throw new \ErrorException('Error executing sp_MyStoredProcedure');
}
```

Do I'm doing this check properly?

Detailed $statement->errorInfo():

```
array (
  0 => '00000',
  1 => 515,
  2 => 'General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [515]  (severity 16) [(null)]',
  3 => -1,
  4 => 16,
)
```

Also according to [article](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-515.aspx) error *515* is an error of inserting NULL into column which is NOT NULL. But why I don't see this error when executing `EXEC [dbo].[sp_MyStoredProcedure] 1, 2, 3` in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or tsql (freetds-bin)?

Comment: You may need to iterate over multiple resultsets. Try to run a loop from [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call) and see whether it throws a PDOException?

Comment: I have tried, but `$statement->nextRowset()` always returns `false`, so I'm assuming I have only single rowset. Maybe the behavior he describes only exists in MySQL, I'm using stored procedures of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Solution - explicitly specify null-ability for temporary tables columns in your stored procedure.

Before:

```
create table #resultsTable(
    paging_id int,
    pt_key bigint,
    pt_ctkeyfrom int
)
```

After:

```
create table #resultsTable(
    paging_id int NULL,
    pt_key bigint NULL,
    pt_ctkeyfrom int NULL
)
```

For me the problem was resolved.

Unfortunately I do not know how to solve without changing the procedure code.

Answer (score -1):

To see your exceptions, you need to catch them when they are thrown. Your code does not listen those `PDOException` because you miss the `try-catch` statement.

Here is an example of error checking when dealing with methods throwing exceptions :

```
$pdo = null;

try {
    $pdo = new \PDO('dblib:host=192.168.0.10:1433;dbname=MyDb;charset=UTF-8', 'mydb', 'secret', [
        \PDO::ATTR_CASE => \PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => \PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
        \PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
    ]);

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("EXEC [dbo].[sp_MyStoredProcedure] 1, 2, 3");

    $data = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch( PDOException $e ) {
    print_r( $pdo->errorInfo() );   //  PDO::errorInfo() returns an array
                                    //  [0] : sql error code
                                    //  [1] : driver error code
                                    //  [2] : error message
}
```

You see that you do not have to throw any custom exceptions, you have to catch them relative to their nature (PDO throws `PDOException`).

You may eventually throw your own exceptions, but you will need to catch them on another block of code. Here is an example that fits your original code :

```
$pdo = null;

try {
    $pdo = new \PDO('dblib:host=192.168.0.10:1433;dbname=MyDb;charset=UTF-8', 'mydb', 'secret', [
        \PDO::ATTR_CASE => \PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => \PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
        \PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
    ]);

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("EXEC [dbo].[sp_MyStoredProcedure] 1, 2, 3");

    if ( ! $statement->execute()) {
        throw new \ErrorException('Error executing sp_MyStoredProcedure');
    }

    $data = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch( PDOException $e ) {
    print_r( $pdo->errorInfo() );   //  PDO::errorInfo() returns an array
                                    //  [0] : sql error code
                                    //  [1] : driver error code
                                    //  [2] : error message
}
catch( ErrorException $e ) {
    print_r( $e );
}
```

Comment: I'm using debugger and executing my code in step by step, so I would see if it is thrown, but it is not.

Comment: You are wrong. You don't need to catch exceptions when they are thrown.

Comment: @YourCommonSense php throws an error if a `try` is not followed by a `catch` statement.